# Problems with an oracle maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to compile a project in Anypoint studio, and for some reason it's failing on one dependency -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
<version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Should say, when I run this on my Windows laptop i have absolutely no issues and the jars download fine. Running it on my macbook, i get the following error -

```
Archive for required library: '/Users/matt/.m2/repository/com/oracle/jdbc/ucp/12.1.0.2/ucp-12.1.0.2.jar' in project 's-wms-hj-api' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    s-wms-hj-api
```

the message i get when i update project dependencies is -

[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Is it something Mac related?

Comment: Note that this question doesn't have a relationship to Mule nor ODBC so the tags are not correct.

Comment: Submitted an edit for the tags. Not sure why this was voted down. The question is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency is not available in public repositories so the jar has to be installed manually in the local Maven repository. The error was likely because it was incorrectly installed.

The warning is the expected result because that method doesn't provide the pom.

I'm not sure why you don't see the warning in Windows. Perhaps a different Maven version or using a repository manager?

Comment: Hi, i've removed the original jars and tried to download again and i get the same error. Maybe it's that the jars already existed on my local machine on Windows so didn't need to download. Ok, ill download manually, thanks.

Comment: You need to install it manually as Maven will not find it, it is not available in the Central Maven repository. You need to install it manually. See Jerney's answer for the method.

Answer (score 0):

I've always dealt with Oracle the following way (I'm running a mac as well, though it really doesn't matter):

Download the `.jar` file from the internet somewhere. Install the dependency using Maven using these instructions: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Here's an example of the command, assuming you downloaded the jar for ucp version 12.1.0.2, you are currently in that directory, and the file is called `ucp-12.1.0.2.jar`:

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=ucp-12.1.0.2.jar \
    -DgroupId=com.oracle.jdbc \
    -DartifactId=ucp \
    -Dversion=12.1.0.2 \
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

This should install into your default `~/.m2/repository`. If you want you can verify this with:

```
ls -al ~/.m2/repository/com/oracle/jdbc/ucp/12.1.0.2.jar
```

You should see a pom file in there.

Maven will now be ready to grab this file when you specify them in your pom. Keep in mind that the groupId, artifactId, and version parameters for the `mvn install` command relate exactly to what you'd put in the pom for those same fields.